# How to filter out the latest date in the excel? look in to the description for more details

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the attached image, for each product ID there is a price associated to it under different price types. i need to filter out the latest date for each of the price type for every product. how to do that in excel?

[image: click here for the image]

Comment: When you say filter out, which do you mean? Find the latest date for each price type with no other details? Find all details for the latest date for each price type? Or hide the rows with the latest date for each price type?

Comment: i would like to get all the details for the latest date for each price type.

Comment: What you probably need is PivotTable. Google it, you will find a lot of examples.

Comment: Nope. I am not looking for pivot table. i am looking for a excel worksheet  which i will be feeding into Tibco Spotfire for making visualizations.

Comment: The input looks good. Can you manually do it and update your desired output also?

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses tables to make the formulas a little easier to follow (and is generally good practice anyway).

In these formulas, your input table is named Table1. Your output table starts with a unique list of ProductIDs and then returns the rest of columns based on the ProductID

FromDate:

```
=MAXIFS(Table1[FromDate],Table1[Productid],[@ProductID])
```

MaxDateRow (This is an array-Formula; save the formula by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` instead of just `ENTER`):

```
=MATCH([@ProductID]&[@FromDate],Table1[Productid]&Table1[FromDate],0)
```

Price:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Price],[@MaxDateRow])
```

Id:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Id],[@MaxDateRow])
```

[image: Tables]

You can remove the helper column MaxDateRow by inserting that formula into the formulas for Price, Id and any other columns. Those entire formulas will just need to saved using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`